# Making Excel Charts Read-Only via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Currently using these commands and have most of the chart locked down.

```
    .ProtectData = True
    .ProtectFormatting = True
    .ProtectSelection = True
```

The problem is it can still be resized by the end user.

What command/property is missing to make this chart sort of "read only" where it can not even be resized?

Comment: What if you protect the worksheet it's on?  I just tried that and I can no longer resize the chart.  Mind you, it may mean you can't perform other functions you want.  Worth a shot anyway.

Comment: Yeah, protecting the sheet would overall give you the security, but can't cherry-pick so to speak, to get what you want. Perhaps a checkbox or two with size settings (i.e. medium, large) that unprotects the sheet, performs the action, then re-protects...

Comment: @JVBA, protecting with *UserInterfaceOnly;=true* would allow the checkbox's vba to do pretty much anything without cycling the protection status.